# start new activity on click listview item

Tags: android, listview

I need some help to do a simple click in a listview item to open a new Activity. I have seen a lot of this kinda issues here but no one helped me.

```
public class CustomListView extends ListActivity {

    private EfficientAdapter adap;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adap);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        startActivity(new Intent(CustomListView.this, next.class));
    }


    public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private Context context;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);


                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private int pos = position;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                    }
                });



            convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            return convertView;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I tried also adding the next code inside of onCreate method from CustomListView class but it doesn't work either

```
ListView lv = getListView();

// listening to single list item on click
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {

        startActivity(new Intent(CustomListView.this, next.class));

  }
});
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is very vague... What happens in the first example when you click on an item? Do you receive any errors? Please post them if you do.

Comment: @DDjordjevic : What is `one` as in `one.this` that you pass in to the `Intent` constructor? Try `CustomListView.this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `onListItemClick()` from your `CustomListView` class and place the `startActivity()` method inside the `convertView.setOnClickListener()`.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), two.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I am sure It is gonna help you and dont set class to an xml file like this;

```
setContentView(R.layout.second);
```

make sure that you did put that code above in your class, else you are gonna get an error while openin a new activity.

```
package com.exampled.list;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String [] names ={
        "Iphone",
        "Samsung",
        "Nokia",
        "Ericsson",
        "BlackBerry",
        "Benq"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,names));
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView Parent, View v, int position,long id){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class)); 
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on : " + names[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `startActivity(new Intent(one.this, two.class));`-code into

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    private int pos = position;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {...}
});
```

What does one.this refer to? It should be a `Context`

Comment: This approach is one of some attempts that I tried, but I got the following errors:
Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type 
  Activity
 - No enclosing instance of the type CustomListView is accessible in scope.
I also changed the one.class for the right class that I am using, sorry for that.

Comment: Try `startActivity(new Intent(context, two.class));`, since a context is passed to the `Adapter`

Comment: -Doesn't works, I also tried before, throws the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity

Comment: Try `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, two.class));`

Comment: Now way.. error:android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.xxx/com.xxx.SingleActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()

Comment: After some days disconnected from the android development, I found quickly the error, nothing related in this scope, so works fine now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In you code `one.this` refers to the `Context`.

Since your Activity's name is `CustomListView`, you should write `CustomListView.this` instead of `one.this`.

You could also use `getApplicationContext()`.